# Two vector layers, same CRS, wrong coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, coordinates

I have two vector shapes, downloaded from government providers, that should be overlapping perfectly but one appears way of to the east of the other one. They are both set to the same CRS.

I work with several other layers too, which all fit perfectly with the first one.  When I load in the second layer (the one that is off) it says "CRS was undefined". I then set it to the project CRS manually.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

[image: Matching Layers]

[image: Not matching Layer]

Comment: Which GIS software do you use? Can you add some screenshot of your layers?

Comment: are you sure you set it to the correct crs?

Comment: the second data set is not in the projection you think it is

Comment: sorry, I'm using QGIS 3.12

I checked the CRS settings over and over, they are set to the same CRS.

What do you mean by its not the projection i think it is?

Comment: If you have several layers displayed properly, and one layer which doesn't fit to them, then this one has wrong CRS settings. We could give you more specific answers if you could give us some more details about your problem. Which CRS is set to your layers? Some screenshots would be helpful too.

Comment: I have added screenshots of the matching and not matching layers and their CRS Setting. Does this help?

Comment: Can you share your files? So I could reproduce your issue and figure out which CRS setting your second layer should have.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IY7AR6As8luHX2VbCy2COZF78XAaHkkZ

th-etrs89utm_land.shp is the one the others match to.
ffh-gebiete__flaechen_.shp is the one that should line up with it as well but doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I set the shapefile "ffh-gebiete__flaechen_.shp" to EPSG 31468 (DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4), then it overlays correctly with the other layer. This means that the underlying coordinates of the shapefile weren't in UTM 32, but DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4.

Once you've set the correct crs, QGIS can handle on-the-fly reprojection, meaning that it can display your shapefiles in the crs of your project, even if the crs of the shapefile is not the same (provided that its crs was set correctly). Of course, you could also save your layer as UTM 32N, which would effectively recompute the coordinates in the shapefile to UTM 32N.

[image]

Comment: I think I get it :D
Thank you very much for your help!